# PrimeNG - Filter table by indexed element of property array

Tags: datatable, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to implement **data filtering** in a `PrimeNG` table, according to an **indexed** element of a property of my model.

Model example in **JSON format** below:

```
{
"customObj":{
  "id":1,
  "name":"my name",
  "labels":[
     {
        "id":1,
        "labelValue":"A random label"
     },
     {
        "id":2,
        "labelValue":"A random label 2"
     }
  ]
 }
}
```

Considering the model above, I would like to filter the table by `customObj.labels[0].labelValue` property.

Which is the **most out of the box way** to achieve this in a PrimeNG table?

Until now I used for single object properties filtering the `columnFilter` component as shown below

```
<!-- example of filtering for the name property -->
<th>
  <p-columnFilter type="text" field="name"></p-columnFilter> 
</th>
```

can I use something similar to this? I have read the `PrimeNG` documentation but did not find any example on this. Thanks in advance

**Angular version: 12.2.3**

**PrimeNG version: 12.1**

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v12-lts/#/table/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **simplest solution** I finally found to filter the table **by indexed element of array property** is using the `<p-columnFilter` as shown below:

```
<!-- Filter customObj by 'labels[0].labelValue-->
<th>
 <p-columnFilter type="text" field="labels.0.labelValue"></p-columnFilter> 
</th>
```

If the index is in variable form and we do not know it beforehand you can also use variable as shown below:

```
<!-- Filter customObj by 'labels[index].labelValue-->
<th>
 <p-columnFilter type="text" field="labels.{{index}}.labelValue"></p-columnFilter> 
</th>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Have you also entered p-sortIcon?